# MySQL - Select number of entries the last 7 days

Tags: mysql

This is how my table looks like

```
-----------------------
  posts
----------------------
id
created_at
..
..
```

How should the MySQL Query look like, so that i get the number of entries the last 7 days. 
The result should look something like that:
`['Mon' => 234, 'Tues' => 12, ...]`

Comment: have you checked my edited query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `datediff` for that

```
select count(*), extract(day from created_at) current_day
from posts
where datediff(now(), created_at) <= 7
group by current_day;
```

If you want 0 values for other day, then you would have to use a left join on a fake table that generate last seven days.

```
select count(posts.created_at) as nb_occurence, c.a as number_of_day
from
(select b.a
    from (select 1 a
                union all select 2 a
                union all select 3 a
                union all select 4 a
                union all select 5 a
                union all select 6 a
                union all select 7 a) b) c
left join posts on extract(day from posts.created_at) % 7 - c.a in (select extract(day from date_sub(created_at, INTERVAL 7 DAY)) % 7 from posts)
group by c.a;
```

Comment: I already have something like that, but my problem is that i get all entries. But i want just one entry with the day and the number of records.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM posts
WHERE created_at<xy
GROUP BY created_at
```

Comment: My problem is that my `created_at` is not only the day, it has hours, minutes and seconds too.

Comment: `WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF('DAY',created_at,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())<8`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%a')
FROM posts
WHERE created_at <= NOW() AND created_at >= DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%a')
```

To add 0 for weekday having null in count:

```
SELECT a.weekday, IFNULL(b.total,0) FROM 
(SELECT 'Mon' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Tue' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Wed' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Thu' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Fri' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Sat' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Sun' as weekday from dual) a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as total, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%a') as weekday
FROM posts
WHERE created_at <= NOW() AND created_at >= DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%a')) b on a.weekday=b.weekday
```

Comment: Thank you. Right now the best answer. I just have entries from today and yesterday. Is it possible to set all other days to `0`?

Comment: Tested on fiddle: SELECT a.weekday, IFNULL(b.total,0) as total FROM 
(SELECT 'Mon' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Tue' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Wed' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Thu' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Fri' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Sat' as weekday from dual union SELECT 'Sun' as weekday from dual) a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT COUNT(*) as total, DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%a') as weekday
FROM posts
WHERE created_at <= NOW() AND created_at >= DATE_SUB(created_at, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%a')) b on a.weekday=b.weekday